# accessing yahoo and rediff mail using java mail api

Tags: java

How can i use the java mail api for showing mail from yahoo and rediff ?
I used the same code as with gmail mails but now it is giving the :

```
               ***javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException***
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at what the java mail client [columba](http://sourceforge.net/projects/columba/) does. The actual imap and pop clients are extracted into a subproject, that can be used independently from the app.